# How do you get rid of title at the top of navigation bar, but keep title in the item?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a nav bar application that uses a custom header that I created like this:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (Background)

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

UIImage *customLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavBar.png"];
[customLogo drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

}

@end
```

I'm trying to get rid of the title at the top without getting rid of the word showing up in the Navigation Item. These are the variables I have set up in my viewController:

```
    NSArray *tableDataSource;
NSString *CurrentTitle;
NSInteger CurrentLevel;
```

Here's where I think the problem is:

```
if(CurrentLevel == 0) {

NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
self.tableDataSource = tempArray;
[tempArray release];

self.tableDataSource = [self.industryData objectForKey:@"Rows"];
self.navigationItem.title = @"Back";

}
else
    self.navigationItem.title = CurrentTitle;
}
```

If I set the navigationitem.title = nil, I can no longer back up. Is there a way that I can make the title disappear without losing it in the navigationcontroller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the button to say `back` you are going the wrong way about it.

You need some code like this placed in the view controller

```
  UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                            target:nil
                                                            action:nil];

 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
 [backButton release]; backButton = nil;
```

Now when the next page is pushed onto the stack the back button will say `back` instead of the `title` of the controller we just came from.

Now if you want the back button to say the `title` of the previous view controller but you do not want the title to be displayed across the top when you are currently viewing the view controller. You can simply set the title view to a blank view like this:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the title like this..

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"";
```

That should do it, if not read on...

It could also be that your NSString isn't initialised. Try this.

```
NSString *currentString = @"";
```

That way your not going to be setting your navigation item to nil by saying it equals CurrentString.
Another pointer, I never set variables with a capital letter for the first word. Makes things confusing with set words...

Comment: It gets rid of the title but it also gets rid of the Navigation Item.

Comment: The method I have said above would get rid of the title because all I'm doing is setting the title to blank.  Are you sure your navigation item is set up correctly?

Comment: Setting the title to an empty string like that will remove the back button completely on my quick mock up.